# Sql Lite :- near "UNSIGNED": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
string createAppUserTableSQL = @"CREATE TABLE Alarm (  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTOINCREMENT,  title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, description TINYTEXT NOT NULL, status  ENUM('pending','enabled','disabled','retired') NOT NULL,create_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,modify_date TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,modify_user INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,modify_reason TINYTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),INDEX `alarm_index` (`id` ASC, `title` ASC))ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8";
```

Please Help that how to solve this problem

Comment: This statement uses MySQL-specific features. See the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: why are you using <br/> in sql query?

Comment: Read a good book about SQL as a start..

Comment: CL I will Try this but in my Condition both statement (UNSIGNED  & AUTOINCREMENT ) it give Error

Comment: Soner Gönül :- what are you saying man? If you know that what is answer that show your knowledge otherwise don't comment for anybody

Answer (score 2):

1. SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); all these specific data types are pretty much ignored.
2. A field length (like `(10)`) must come at the end of the data type. (But it's ignored anyway.)
3. An [autoincrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) requires INTEGER, not INT.
4. SQLite has no ENUM. To enforce this restriction, you could use a CHECK constraint.
5. There is no special data type for timestamps. SQLite uses strings (default) or numbers.
6. A table definition can contain column constraints and table constraints, but a 'normal' index is not such a constraint. To create an index, use a separate CREATE INDEX statement.
7. Escaping identifiers with `backticks` is a MySQL quirk; standard SQL would use "double quotes".
8. SQLite has no ENGINE or DEFAULT CHARACTER SET options.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Alarm (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'enabled', 'disabled', 'retired')),
    create_date TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modify_date TEXT,
    modify_user INTEGER,
    modify_reason TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX alarm_index ON Alarm(id, title);
```